# Help regarding Facebook Connect...!

Tags: facebook

I have completed the facebook connect process.  I need to address the following issues....

1. If a user has authorised my application: then on pressing F5, he must automatically be signed in...
2. If the user logs out of my site, he must log out of faceboook as well, and then display a dialog message.

Please help

Comment: What's your question? There's not enough detail here to help you

Comment: @paul... I need to perform log out of my site as well as facebook when a user is logged in via facebook...secondly, when a user has authorised my app via his fb account, on going to my homepage, he must be automatically be logged in via his fb account...

Comment: everything works fine... please check social.ndtv.com, once the user has connected via fb, on going to the site again, he is automatically taken to home.php, and while signing out from that, he is shown a message that he is logged out of both fb and the site...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to redirect the user to Facebook's logout page. I doubt it works but it might be the only possibility.

Why do you want to log the user out of Facebook anyway? As a user I'd be pretty pissed about that, but then again I don't know what kind of app this is so it might make sense in some custom Facebook interface or something.

Comment: everything works fine... please check social.ndtv.com, once the user has connected via fb, on going to the site again, he is automatically taken to home.php, and while signing out from that, he is shown a message that he is logged out of both fb and the site...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
<a href="/my_logout" onclick="FB.logout(); return false">logout</a>
```

However, it's rather user-hostile: unless I (the user) have asked you to do that, why the ********** are you logging me out of Facebook?